# how to add a custom menu in asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am work in asp.net core with visual studio 2007,
i did the following:

1. create a folder Components in my project
2. create a viewcomponent

the code:

```
public class TaskViewComponent : ViewComponent
{

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string Id)
    {
        var data = await Task.Run(() => Id.Trim());
        return View("Default", data);
    }
}
```

3. create viewcomponent implement in /Views/Shared/Components/Task/Default.cshtml

[image]

my question is how to add a right menu in cshtml,just like [Go To Component],when click then go to TaskViewComponent in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no context menu for Components as we have for Controller and views to switch back and forth between them.

Comment: What a pity, is there any other way?